# class based to functional component react

Tags: reactjs

just stuck on this while converting class base component to functional base component in react js? having difficulty on following this link example  :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks
for convertion?

**code**
import React,{useState} from 'react'

```
    function Rowadd() {
        const [state, setState] = useState({
            flag: false,
            fields: [],
            Namefield: { value: '', error: '' },
            Emailfield: { value: '', error: '' },
            Mobilefield: { value: '', error: '' },
            tablerows: []
          });
          const handleName = (e) => {
            setState({
            ...state,
            Namefield: {
              value: e.target.value,
              error: false
            }
          })
    
        };
        const handleMobile = (e) => {
            setState({
            ...state,
            Mobilefield: {
              value: e.target.value,
              error: false
            }
          })
    
        };
        const handleMail = (e) => {
            setState({
            ...state,
            Emailfield: {
              value: e.target.value,
              error: false
            }
          })
    
        };
    
        const addRow(e) 
        {
        e.preventDefault();
            var newdata = { name: this.state.Namefield.value, mobile: this.state.Mobilefield.value, mail: this.state.Emailfield.value }
            // //take the existing state and concat the new data and set the state again
            setState({ tablerows: state.tablerows.concat(newdata), flag: true });
        
            const name1 = state.Namefield;
            const mob1 = state.Mobilefield;
            const mail1 = state.Emailfield;
        
            if (name1.value !== "") {
              const newName = [...state.fields, name1]
              this.setState({
                fields: newName,
                Namefield: {
                  value: '',
                  error: ''
                }
              })
            }
        
            if (mob1.value !== "") {
              const newMob = [...state.fields, mob1]
              setState({
                fields: newMob,
                Mobilefield: {
                  value: '',
                  error: ''
                }
              })
            }
        
            if (mail1.value !== "") {
              const newMail = [...state.fields, mail1]
              setState({
                fields: newMail,
                Emailfield: {
                  value: '',
                  error: ''
                }
              })
            }
        
          }
        
          deleteRow(passedID) 
          {
            let tablerows = [...state.tablerows]
            tablerows.splice(passedID, 1)
            setState({
              tablerows: tablerows
            })
          }
        
          editRow = (index, type, values) => {
        
            const newState = tablerows.map((item, i) => {
              if (i === index) {
                return { ...item, [type]: values };
              }
              return item;
            });
            this.setState({
              tablerows: newState
            });
        
          }
    
        return (
            <div>
    <header className="App-header">Sample CRUD Operations</header>
            <form >
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={state}
                onChange={handleName} />       <br />
              <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="Mobile"
                maxLength="10"
                value={state}
                onChange={handleMobile} />          <br />
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                value={state.Emailfield}
                onChange={handleMail} />          <br />
              <div>
                <button onClick={addRow}>ADD</button>
              </div>
            </form>
    
            {this.state.tablerows.length > 0 ?
              <table style={{ "backgroundColor": "rgb(192, 217, 236)" }}>
                <thead style={{ "backgroundColor": "rgb(73, 116, 201)", "color": "white" }}>
                  <tr style={{ "height": "50px" }}>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.tablerows.map((row, index) =>
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td> <input
                        type="text"
                        value={row.name}
                        onChange={(e) => editRow(index, "name", e.target.value)} /></td>
                      <td> <input
                        type="number"
                        maxLength="10"
                        value={row.mobile}
                        onChange={(e) => editRow(index, "mobile", e.target.value)} /></td>
                      <td> <input
                        type="email"
                        value={row.mail}
                        onChange={(e) => editRow(index, "mail", e.target.value)} /></td>
                      <td><button className="deleteBtn" onClick={() => deleteRow(index)}>-</button></td>
                    </tr>)}
                </tbody>
              </table> : ""}
          </div>
        );
    
    }
    
    export default Rowadd
```

Comment: What is the difficulty that you are facing?

Comment: Issues whuile converting that code to functional how manage this.state and so on in functional

Comment: @Imanpal Singh can you clarifies above problem